# Show viewport value in html with live update on-change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a `<p>` element somewhere on my page, and I want it to contain the viewport value, which I can get with:

```
<p>
  <script>
    document.write($(this).width());
  </script>
</p>
```

But it shows it "statically". How can I get this value to update dynamically (showing the live actual value) when I resize the browser viewport?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, maybe it will be usefull, done it with following code, not shure it's the best solution, but it works! Maybe someone can improve it or suggest another, more simple way.

```
            window.onresize = resize;

            function resize() {
                var viewPort = $(window).width();
                $("#window").text(viewPort);
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to attach the function to the resize event of the window.

Check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536959%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).